# Como deixar mais de um painel transparente?

Tags: java, swing

Implementando a resposta [desta questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205164/java-custom-shaped-frame-using-image), eu consegui deixar um painel transparente. Porém, para poder organizar da maneira que eu quero, queria usar mais `JPanels`, com diferentes gerenciadores de layout.

Mas quando eu faço isso, eles não ficam transparentes. Como eu poderia fazer isso ?

Exemplo do problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem é só esse shape azul ai, esse fundo cinza/branco, é do componente.

Quando uso um painel só:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Teste {

    public Teste() {
        JWindow jWindow = new JWindow();
        jWindow.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        jWindow.setContentPane(new Pane());
        jWindow.pack();
        jWindow.setVisible(true);
        jWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    class Pane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage leaf;

        public Pane() {
            //setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel borderPainel = new JPanel();
            borderPainel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel gridPainel = new JPanel();
            gridPainel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

            gridPainel.add(new JLabel("Label 01"));
            gridPainel.add(new JLabel("Label 02"));

            borderPainel.add(gridPainel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(borderPainel);

            try {
                leaf = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/imagens/icon.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            gridPainel.setOpaque(false);
            borderPainel.setOpaque(false);
            //setOpaque(false);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return leaf == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(leaf.getWidth(), leaf.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (leaf != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.drawImage(leaf, 0, 0, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        new Teste();
    }
}
```

Comment: seu codigo nao é [mcve] por causa da imagem, se possivel, fornecer a imagem para que a reproducao seja mais fiel possivel do problema.

Comment: Sobrescreva o método paint do panel abaixo, tirando chamada ao paint do pai por um paint components do panel filho

Comment: Mal pergunte porque ta usando jwindow? Imagino que o deveria usar JFrame

Comment: @Sveen o metodo paint nao deve ser sobrescrito.

Comment: O método não é protegido contra sobreescrita, e já realizei inúmeras vezes isso

Comment: @Sveen so porque nao é protegido nao significa que é o certo a se fazer. O java nao bloqueia nada, se voce quiser fazer errado, é por conta do programador esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: @Articuno poderia ser qualquer imagem, por exemplo, se você colocar uma bola, ele vai ficar com o fundo retangular (padrão do componente), em vez de ficar transparente, mais eu vou adicionar um print

Comment: @Javinha é importante voce fornecer a sua ou uma equivalente senao a reproducao do erro pode ser diferente do que voce está enfrentando

Comment: Executei aqui e nao entendi o problema do codigo. O que precisa ficar transparente?

Comment: @Articuno editei lá, eu também tinha uma dúvida sobre o porque ele não respeitou a posição dos componentes, mais vou aguardar um direcionamento sobre a transparência primeiro.

Comment: @Articuno editado !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz 3 alterações no código:

- alterei `JWindow` para `JFrame`, pois já que está trabalhando com a API swing, utilize componentes desta API e não do *awt*;
- eu já te avisei várias vezes em outros posts, mas aviso novamente: *SEMPRE* despache aplicação gráfica dessa API para a [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread);
- apenas descomentei a linha `setOpaque(false);` que torna o `JFrame` transparente tambem.

O código ficou assim:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class PainelTransparenteTest {

    public PainelTransparenteTest() {
        JFrame jWindow = new JFrame();
        jWindow.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        jWindow.setContentPane(new Pane());
        jWindow.pack();
        jWindow.setVisible(true);
        jWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    class Pane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage leaf;

        public Pane() {
            //setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel borderPainel = new JPanel();
            borderPainel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel gridPainel = new JPanel();
            gridPainel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

            gridPainel.add(new JLabel("Label 01"));
            gridPainel.add(new JLabel("Label 02"));

            borderPainel.add(gridPainel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(borderPainel);

            try {
                //leaf = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/imagens/icon.png"));
                leaf = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5lmv.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            gridPainel.setOpaque(false);
            borderPainel.setOpaque(false);
            setOpaque(false);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return leaf == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(leaf.getWidth(), leaf.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (leaf != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.drawImage(leaf, 0, 0, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->  new PainelTransparenteTest());
    }
}
```

E o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O truque aqui foi configurar para que a tela principal(o `JFrame` neste caso) não seja opaco também, dai ele seguirá o background dos componentes internos. Por isso bastou descomentar a linha informada.

Comment: mais uma coisa, o que eu fiz de errado, para os labels não ficarem setados na posição SOUTH?

Comment: @Javinha ai ja e um a duvida completamente diferente da pergunta. Mas suponho q o problema seja nessa classe de painel que voce criou e dentro dela criou mais dois paineis. A dica para identificar que posso dar é botar bordas em todos os paineis de cores diferentes, assim voce vai enxergar os limites de cada um e ver o que pode estar causando isso.